# How can I find the roots of a polynomial in the form of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Given the polynomial $f=\left|\begin{matrix} x & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & x & 2 \\ 1 & x & x \end{matrix}\right|$, what would the roots for $f=0$ be, and how can I find them?

Comment: Have you tried just working out what polynomial $f$ is? Don't be scared by the $x$s, just treat it like any old determinant.

Comment: It is not a matrix, it is the determinant of a matrix. expand the determinant, you get an ordinary polynomial in $x$: $x^3-2x^2-x-2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ \det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x & -1 & 1\\
0 & x & 2\\
1 & x & x
\end{bmatrix}\right) =x^{3} -2x^{2} -x-2$$
Which has roots at $x\approx 2.659$, $x\approx -0.32948-0.80225i$, and $x\approx 0.32948+0.80225i$.